# Mysql root password problems

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have installed mysql on a mac 10.7, I am using phpmyadmin to access the mysql database but am getting locked out with an error when i try to login with a username root no password

```
Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)
```

when i put a password root with the same username, i get an error,

```
#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

What is the root password in mysql and how can i change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password new_password_here
```

To change the password to `new_password_here` in a fresh install.
You can then use thtat to login to phpMyAdmin.

phpMyAdmin default is to set [AllowNoPassword](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config/Servers#AllowNoPassword) to false, for security reasons. So you have to set a password first.

Answer (score 3):

As @Jacob mention you need to set you password for security reason but I am using phpmyadmin for study purpose so I change few settings which works for me.

```
Step 1: Change config.sample.inc.php to config.inc.php

Step 2: Find the line  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
                 and change it to 
          $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';

Step 3: Find the line that says 
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
                and change it to 
         $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

hope that helps. But remember while working with DB always think about the security of you data. So i suggest you to set password and be safe.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is a recurring question/problem with PHPMyAdmin. Today I installed Ubuntu 18.04 with MariaDB and PHPMyAdmin 4.6.6deb5.  This is the info that I should have had before my installation of PHPMyAdmin.  Though I used MariaDB, I presume this would also apply to MySQL.

The trick is to install PHPMyAdmin after installing MariaDB and BEFORE running `mysql_secure_installation`.  At this state the MariaDB root password is empty.  However PHPMyAdmin will not allow you to login as root with an empty password, therefore you have to run `mysql_secure_installation` from the terminal and set a root password for MariaDB.

In my experience you may have to, no make that **WILL HAVE TO**, reset the database root password to [NULL] if you already have an existing root password for MariaDB **before installing PHPMyAdmin**. If you already have a root password for MariaDB, you will have to login from a terminal with `mysql -u root -p` and enter the root password. Then you have to execute this query in order to set the database root password to null:

`SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('');`

and only install PHPMyAdmin once the MariaDB password has been set to zero.  Then you will again have to execute `mysql_secure_installation` as root in order to set a strong password for MariaDB.

I suspect that a lot of the confusion with PHPMyAdmin passwords seems to originate due to users not realising that the username/password that PHPMyAdmin refers to are the MySQL/MariaDB database user names and passwords and not any password specific to PHPMyAdmin.